# C# Copy URL when it changes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows form application with a browser added in. I would like it so when the URL changes, say when navigating to a new page, that it copies the new URL. How can I achieve this?

Searched everywhere with no results.

Comment: I removed ithe "asp.net" and "visual-studio" tags as the Web server technology and the development environment are not related to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this with the [Navigated Event.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

```
// Navigated event
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    string url = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
    //COPY THE URL HERE HOWEVER YOU LIKE
}
```